# "your connection is not private" on linux, but ok on windows

Tags: linux, networking, windows

I'm using linux and windows in a medium sized company (large enough that the systems people are in a different city).

On linux, chrome and firefox refuse to connect to some popular websites
that require https: connection, saying "your connection is not private" and
some error about the certificate.  Twitter is an example (I'm not going to twitter to post, just to read something that I was directed to read). 
On the other hand, gmail (which also uses https) is accessible on linux .
[This is on an up-to-date Ubuntu system, version 16.x]

The puzzling thing (for me): on Windows, there is no problem, no websites are blocked.

What could be causing this? Any hints on how to go about debugging it?

Please keep the answer fairly simple. I know a little programming, but nothing about systems or networking.

Comment: Different allowed certificate authorities and chain files, etc. installed.  If you examine the certificate under linux, what makes it untrusted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your company and/or whoever manages your computer systems and network specifically your proxy, has it configured to monitor all network traffic from their systems.  These days it is normal and is done by having a trusted certificate authority specified, typically in Internet Explorer, that is by your company or network administrator.  In order for you to get https connection at some external site, you have to go through **their** proxy and also have **their** trusted certificate.  Technically this amounts to a type of man in the middle attack, as your company will know what you are doing when you connect to whatever https site.  If you think your encrypted connection between IE on your pc and `https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl` for example is between just you and google think again.  Technically you are encrypted first between your IE and your proxy and the admins controlling that proxy server will know everything you do, as that proxy then hands off that SSL communication to whatever external site you were going to.

problem with your linux system because it is a different system not managed by your company or network admins does not have your company's trusted certificate. You need to manually export it from IE on your company's computer, then import it into firefox/chrome/whatever browser on a given computer system.  Also be aware in linux that the browsers can use a different SSL than what is defaulted on the system which might be under `/etc/ssl/certs`.

This is to say if you manually import a cert into `/etc/ssl/certs` so your linux OS can get to update repositories for patching like for SUSE or Redhat, don't expect firefox to work even though you tell it to use system settings.  Same goes if you manually import certs into firefox, don't expect the kernel and any online update manager to know anything about it.

**IE - tool - internet options - Content - Certificates - Trusted Root Certificate Authorities**

this will be populated on your windows pc, look for the one(s) that stand out and most likely will have your Company's or Corporations's name.  Export this to a file you can copy to your linux or other system.

**Firefox: tools - options - advanced - certificates - view certificates - authorities - import**

To update a Linux system, I know how to do it on **SLES** under /etc/ssl/certs.  It amounts to exporting the SSL from IE in the correct format, then copying the file over to linux.  IE exports in CER format, and linux want PEM format so you will need to copy the CER files over to linux in a temporary folder somewhere and on each do

```
openssl x509   -inform der    -in IE_exported_cert.CER    -out cert_for_linux.PEM
```

copy these PEM files to `/etc/ssl/certs` and within this folder for each PEM file that is a new certificate do

```
ln -s     cert_for_linux.PEM      `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in cert_for_linux.PEM`.0
```